# What is the use of "snprintf" with more than 4 parameters?

Tags: c, printf, linux-device-driver

I have something in my code as below:
This is code for creating a DEVICE in linux under `/dev`

```
#define PRINTER_STR "printer_"
char str[32];
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), PRINTER_STR "%s%s", dev->type, "%u");
device_create(mycan_drv.class, parent,
              MKDEV(dev->nMajor, dev->nMinor),
              dev, str, dev->nMinor);
```

4th parameter to `snprintf` which is `dev->type` is assigned with strings like `epson`,`hp`,`canon`.

Output achieved is something like this :
`printer_epson32`,`printer_hp33`,`printer_canon34`

In the above output strings, I couldnt understand how the numbers like `32`,`33`,`34` are built.
I can understand this is because of the 5th parameter `"%u"` passed to `snprintf`. But how ?

All the references i got are with max 3 or 4 parameters of `snprintf`.
Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried to read the manual page? [snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

Comment: You could have done: `device_create(mycan_drv.class, parent, MKDEV(dev->nMajor, dev->nMinor), dev, PRINTER_STR "%s%u", dev->type, dev->nMinor);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char str[32];
dev->type = "epson";
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "printer_" "%s%s", dev->type, "%u");
```

results in:

```
str = "printer_epson%u".
```

Then code does:

```
device_create(..., str, dev->nMinor);
```

which is really:

```
device_create(..., "printer_epson%u", dev->nMinor);
```

and then inside `device_create` a `*printf` like function is once again called and it writes `dev->nMinor` in place of `%u`. So, like, it's not `snprintf` that writes the number, the number is written inside `device_create`. `snprintf` is used to create the formatting string for `device_create` and `device_create` writes that number.

Side note: The `"%s%s", dev->type, "%u")` looks strange, it could have been just `"%s%%u", dev->type);`. And anyway for all that it could have just been `device_create(...., "%s%u", dev->type, dev->nMinor)`.

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk, your explanation was neat and clear. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler would be:

```
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), PRINTER_STR "%s%%u", dev->type);
```

Since `%u` is a fixed string, it could be just included in the format.  The `%` needs to be escaped to avoid being interpreted by snprintf.